# get selected value in angular ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object like bellow:

```
var data = {
    BCS: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    HND: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    LMU: ['i', 'j', 'l', 'm']
};
```

And Bellow is my controller

```
function getDivision($scope) {
    $scope.divisions = data;
}
```

And this is model

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='getDivision'>
        <select ng-model="key" ng-options="key for (key , val) in divisions" ng-change="update()"></select>
        <select ng-model="divisionValues" ng-options="value for value in key"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ99H/)

How can i get first selected value and parse it to the controller ?

Comment: @MarcKline did you my fiddle ?

Comment: @MarcKline see the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cQ99H/2/

Comment: @MarcKline NOOOO.IT showing selected array.I need the key.When selected HND i need to parse HND to the controller

Comment: come http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions should look like the following:

```
<select ng-model="key"ng-options="key as key for (key, val) in divisions"
ng-change="update()"></select>

<select ng-model="divisionValues"
ng-options="value for value in divisions[key]"></select>
```

This combination will allow your users to select from the keys of `data`, and once they do, the second `select` box will contain the four letters associated with them in the associated value array.

The expressions are tricky and hard to understand at first, but if you read [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) *a few times* and experiment, it will all make sense.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8KX3/2/)

Comment: Do you mean to have 2 ng-model attributes in the first select?

Comment: Yikes. Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the key to the update method like `ng-change="update(key)"`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ99H/3/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='getDivision'>
        <select ng-model="key" ng-options="key as key for (key, val) in divisions" ng-change="update(key)"></select>
        <select ng-model="divisionValues" ng-options="value for value in divisions[key]"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var data = {
    BCS: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    HND: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    LMU: ['i', 'j', 'l', 'm']
};

function getDivision($scope) {
    $scope.divisions = data;
    $scope.update = function (a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}
```